# Camel OnException not catching the exception occured in Route

Tags: apache-camel

I am testing my code for exception handling by provided wrong FTP IP in URL and expecting that exception should be catch inside the onException block and debug statement should be printed in the logs. But its not getting caught inside the exception block.

My route-

```
onException(ClientException.class).process(new Processor() {
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            Exception exception = (Exception) exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT);
            logger.debug("Exception from Route******" + exception.getMessage());
        }
    }).handled(true);

from("file:C:/File-Stuff/File-InBox?noop=true").toD("ftp://10.0.76.1:21/binary=true&password=xxxxxx&username=xxxxx");

Please tell me what I am missing here.

Thanks.
```

Comment: Try replacing `ClientException.class` with just `Exception.class` to catch all exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to catch all exception as Ralf wrote. You can differentiate exceptions by if condition .

```
 onException(Exception.class).process(new Processor() {
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                 if(exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT) instanceof BlaBlaException.class){
                BlaBlaException exception = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, BlaBlaException.class);
                        exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, 500);
                        exchange.getIn().setBody(exception.getMessage());
                    }
        }
                }).handled(true);
```